# Singularity of a surface in $\mathbb{P}(1,1,1,a)$ passing through the vertex

Tags: algebraic-geometry, singularity

I would like to understand better the kind of singularities that we obtain in hypersurfaces in weighted projective spaces. For instance, let us consider the surface $S:x_0^{2a}+x_1^{2a}+x_2^{2a}=0$ of $\mathbb{P}(1,1,1,a)$ with coordinates $(x_0,x_1,x_2,y)$.

If I am not wrong, locally around the vertex $(0:0:0:1)$ this corresponds to the variety $z_0^{2a}+z_1^{2a}+z_2^{2a}=0$ in $\mathbb{A}^3/\mathbb{Z}_a$. Here the action is given by,
$$
(\epsilon, (z_0,z_1,z_2))\mapsto (\epsilon z_0,\epsilon z_1,\epsilon z_2)
$$
where $\epsilon$ is a primitive $a$-root of unity.

So, my question is: what can we say about $(0:0:0:1)\in S$? What kind of singularity do we have there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\mathbb{P}(1,1,1,a)$ is the cone over the $a$-th Veronese embedding of $\mathbb{P}^2$. Consequently, the surface $S$ is the cone over the plane Fermat curve $C$ of degree $2a$ embedded via the complete linear system $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2}(a)\vert_C$.

Comment: Ok, thank you. And could we find a resolution of this singularity taking that into account?

Comment: Of course, if you blowup the vertex of the cone what you get is the ruled surface $\mathbb{P}_C(\mathcal{O}_C \oplus \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2}(a)\vert_C)$.

Comment: Ok, thanks! By the way, $S$ is a cone over that curve because $y$ does not appear in the equation. How could we study the singularity at the vertex of the variety given by $yx_0^a+x_0^{2a}+x_1^{2a}+x_2^{2a}=0$?

Comment: Consider the strict transform of this variety in the blowup of the cone, which is $\mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{P}^2}(\mathcal{O} \oplus \mathcal{O}(a))$. Projection to $\mathbb{P}^2$ identifies it with the blowup of $\mathbb{P}^2$ along the subscheme defined by $\{x_0^a = x_1^{2a} + x_2^{2a} = 0\}$, i.e., disjoint union of $2a$ nilpotent subschemes of length $a$. In particular, it has $2a$ singularities of type $A_{a-1}$. This might be useful for the study of the singularity.